# Cast an Object (Of Class having Parameters)

Tags: .net, .net-core

Dot Net Core project I'm working on, but I welcome Dot Net Framework's input leading to ideas for Dot Net Core.

The casting of class object works like this.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}

Foo foo1 = new Foo() { Value1 = "1", Value2 = "2" };
var foo2 = (object)foo1;
var foo3 = (Foo)foo2;
```

That works but what about the class having constructor?  (In this case, say I have 20 webservice classes where I can make the script shorter by eliminating too many declarations and scripts).

Can this be done, or not?  Just wondering because down the road, when we keep adding more webservice class - it becomes unsustainable.

```
public class Foo1
{
   public Foo(string value1, string value2)
   {
   }
   public void Method1()
   {
   }
}
public class Foo2
{
   public Foo(string value1, string value2)
   {
   }
   public void Method2()
   {
   }
}
//public class Example
//{
    object foo;
    var foo1 = new Foo1("1","2");
    var foo2 = new Foo2("1","2");

    foo = (Foo1)foo1;
    foo.Method1();

    foo = (Foo2)foo2;
    foo.Method2();
//}
```

Comment: I've read this question 3 times now but still don't really understand what you're asking...

Comment: Why do you need to assign these to an `object` before calling the methods?

Comment: Programmers at my job, are very influent and source-code heavy in interface & abstract.  Only people like them would understand this.  Or a better analogy would be like explaining Calculus 4 to 1st graders who only understand Addition & Substraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that, since that two foos are different objects. It could be done if you have the same interface.

```
    public interface IFoo
    {

    }

    public class Foo1 : IFoo
    {
        public Foo1(string v1, string v2)
        {

        }


        public void Method1()
        {

        }

    }

    public class Foo2 : IFoo
    {
        public Foo2(string v1, string v2)
        {

        }

        public void Method2()
        {

        }


    }


    public class test
    {
       public void TestFoo()
       {
                Foo1 foo1 = new Foo1("test", "test2");
                    Foo2 foo2 = new Foo2("test1", "test2");
                    IFoo foo = foo2;
                   ((Foo2)foo).Method2();
      }
   }
```

Comment: I see what you mean now.  That make sense.